# i am trying to run a hello world program in c in visual studio code but its not working

Tags: c

this is my program

```c
#include stdio.h

int main(){
    printf("hello world");
    return = 0;
}
```

when I run it in vs code it says

'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

what is broken and how do I fix it

I do have the c/c++ extension installed, I also have code runner installed

I also have looked around the internet for a solution, but none of them really made sense to me when I searched for them i copied and pasted the error message

Comment: What basic troubleshooting have you done? Obvious things like - is `gcc` installed - should be included in the question. Be aware that VS Code is an IDE but does not include a C compiler.

Comment: And, when you've resolved whatever is causing that issue, you'll need to add some angle-brackets in `#include <stdio.h>` and remove the `=` after `return`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are several basic errors here, and all of them are best addressed by either *following a tutorial to the letter*, or by asking on an actual *discussion forum*. "I also have looked around the internet for a solution, but none of them really made sense to me" Then I don't understand why you expect it to be any different here. We can't even have any idea *what* you saw or *why* it didn't make sense to you, so how can we possibly make it any easier to understand?

Comment: For example, when you looked around the internet, did you try putting `visual studio code can't find gcc` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=visual+studio+code+can%27t+find+gcc)? What exactly was unhelpful about those results? Maybe you could try `visual studio code install gcc`? Or copying and pasting the complete error message, that works too, sometimes.

Comment: "*I do have the c/c++ extension installed*". The extension is not the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install either the GCC or G++ compilers. Assuming you are on linux, it's `sudo apt install gcc`.

Comment: Please don't ever suggest anything starting with `sudo` to someone whose apparent level of understanding is this low.

Comment: While I strongly disagree with the previous comment as it is too absolutist, I would like to point out 3 problems with your answers: 1) based on the wording of the error OP is getting they are on windows, not Linux 2) Not all Linux distributions use apt 3) Not all Linux distributions enable sudo by default.